# How to send raw HTTP Post request

Tags: python, python-requests

I have raw HTTP post requests from a proxy tool. I want to repeat those requests using Python, but the problem I see is Python's `requests` module needs request body to be categorized as cookies, url, headers etc. Is there any other way to directly send a post request like the one below without any parsing on them?

```
POST /ping HTTP/1.1
Host: api-ping.intercom.io
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: https://google.com
Cookie: fbtagfired=1; XSRF-TOKEN=ZSvws4XGAi5xJ7YXVtNXaKC5BWnkfuq%5FfFWNW3AIHF8; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1471151696291r0.5966759731131964; optimizelySegments=%7B%22298381354%22%3A%22ff%22%2C%22298764299%22%3A%22direct%22%2C%22298833008%22%3A%22false%22%2C%225339512050%22%3A%22none%22%2C%225679980916%22%3A%22true%22%2C%226343420664%22%3A%22true%22%2C%226332454984%22%3A%22true%22%2C%225637610161%22%3A%22Custom%22%2C%225758861514%22%3A%22false%22%7D; optimizelyBuckets=%7B%7D; 
Content-Length: 176
Origin: https://google.com
Connection: keep-alive

app_id=rtd418mk&user_data=%7B%7D&referer=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.com%2Fd%2Flogin&widget_src=%5B%22https%3A%2F%2Fwidget.intercom.io%2Fwidget%2Frtd418mk%22%5D&Idempotency-Key=2ceffee9
```

Comment: Simple way is to use TCP client [https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication)

Comment: hey @Logman using that can i send raw http Post request like above and get response ?

Comment: yes but response will also be as raw text (bytes)